# How do I retrieve some information from HTML code in AHK?

Tags: javascript, autohotkey

I'd like to retrieve some information from HTML code. Let's consider the following:

```
<ul class="article-additional-info">
   <li><strong>Issue Year:</strong> 2011</li>
   <li><strong>Issue No:</strong> 1 (200)</li>
   <li><strong>Page Range:</strong> 65-80</li>
   <li><strong>Page Count:</strong> 15</li>
   <li><strong>Language:</strong> Polish</li>
</ul>
```

I can get all the information from `article-additional-info` class by using `document.getElementsByClassName("article-additional-info")[0].innerText`.

But how do I retrieve individual information from this class like `2011` (from `<strong>Issue Year:</strong> 2011<`)?
I'd like to avoid using RegEx.

**EDIT:**

Based on the answer, I slightly modified the code. However, I cannot get rid of one element: `Language:`. Here's the code:

```
html =
(
<body>
<ul class="article-additional-info">
   <li><strong>Issue Year:</strong> 2011</li>
   <li><strong>Issue No:</strong> 1 (200)</li>
   <li><strong>Page Range:</strong> 65-80</li>
   <li><strong>Page Count:</strong> 15</li>
   <li><strong>Language:</strong> Polish</li>
</ul>
</body>
)

document := ComObjCreate("HTMLfile")
document.write(html)

test := ["Issue Year:", "Issue No:", "Page Range:", "Page Count:"]

try While (x := document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[A_Index-1])
    {
    if (x.className = "article-additional-info")
        {
        count++
        yclass%count% := x.innerHTML
        }
    }

loop, %count%
{
html := yclass%A_Index%
document.Close
document := ComObjCreate("HTMLfile")
document.write(html)

try While (x := document.getElementsByTagName("strong")[A_Index-1])
    {
    StringLen, y, % test[A_Index]
    msgbox % [A_Index] . " " . substr(x.parentnode.innerText, y+2)
    }
}
ExitApp
```

Comment: How is this related to Windows Autohotkey ?

Comment: AHK is a language that can use `getElementsByClassName`. This is why it is related, because I'd like to use this function in AHK. If I didn't want to use it in AHK, it wouldn't be related to AHK.

Comment: Get the position of </strong>, and substring everything after that?

Comment: Skimming through the [documentation](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm#s5) and other [AHK questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autohotkey) on Stack Overflow, it doesn't seem to look anything like javascript, and it's really confusing why you would be using a scripting language for creating macros used with hotkeys in Windows, to access a document and HTML elements, I don't think I've seen anything like that before? Anyway, -> https://jsfiddle.net/hcsprd80/

Comment: @adeneo Using AHK to access some information in HTML code (and simulating clicking etc.) is very common in AHK. See for example [How to automate a Web-Login ?](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/80590-how-to-automate-a-web-login-requires-ie/). Thanks for your code. It shows all the information in `article-additional-info`. Can you access only part of it (e.g. `2011` or `Polish`)?

Comment: An edit: I haven't seen jsfiddle.net before and I missed the Run button.

Comment: @menteith In your edited example, you have removed "Language:" from the array of variables so you will have to add a line to only look at instances of <Strong> that match the remaining array variables. So change the `test array` to delete `Language` (leave the quotes as this establishes the instance number of the `<Strong>` elements) and add this line `if (test[A_Index] <> "")` right after the line `StringLen, y, % test[A_Index]` and then you can pick and choose which variables to use in the test array. I did that in my example below, too. Let me know if it works, pls! Thx,

Comment: Thanks! I will test it as soon as I am at my computer.

Comment: Sorry, for late reply. I have had a lot on my mind. It works fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like so:

```
html =
(
<body>
<ul class="article-additional-info">
   <li><strong>Issue Year:</strong> 2011</li>
   <li><strong>Issue No:</strong> 1 (200)</li>
   <li><strong>Page Range:</strong> 65-80</li>
   <li><strong>Page Count:</strong> 15</li>
   <li><strong>Language:</strong> Polish</li>
</ul>
<ul class="article-additional-info">
   <li><strong>Issue Year:</strong> XX 2011</li>
   <li><strong>Issue No:</strong> XX 1 (200)</li>
   <li><strong>Page Range:</strong> XX 65-80</li>
   <li><strong>Page Count:</strong> XX 15</li>
   <li><strong>Language:</strong> XX Polish</li>
</ul>
</body>
)

test := "Language:"  ;  adjust for the variable you want to return
classno := 1  ;  adjust the number for the correct class instance!

document := ComObjCreate("HTMLfile")
document.write(html)

try While (x := document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[A_Index-1])
    {
    if (x.className = "article-additional-info")
        yclass%A_Index% := x.innerHTML
    }
html := yclass%classno%

document.Close
document := ComObjCreate("HTMLfile")
document.write(html)

try While (x := document.getElementsByTagName("strong")[A_Index-1])
    {
    StringLen, y, test
    if (x.innerText = test)
        msgbox % substr(x.parentnode.innerText, y+2)  ;  returns "Polish"
    }
ExitApp
```

And, if you want to iterate over all the class instances and for all the variables, just do it like so:

```
html =
(
<body>
<ul class="article-additional-info">
   <li><strong>Issue Year:</strong> 2011</li>
   <li><strong>Issue No:</strong> 1 (200)</li>
   <li><strong>Page Range:</strong> 65-80</li>
   <li><strong>Page Count:</strong> 15</li>
   <li><strong>Language:</strong> Polish</li>
</ul>
<ul class="ao">
   <li><strong>Issue Year:</strong> zz 2011</li>
   <li><strong>Issue No:</strong> zz 1 (200)</li>
   <li><strong>Page Range:</strong> zz 65-80</li>
   <li><strong>Page Count:</strong> zz 15</li>
   <li><strong>Language:</strong> zz Polish</li>
</ul>
<ul class="article-additional-info">
   <li><strong>Issue Year:</strong> XX 2011</li>
   <li><strong>Issue No:</strong> XX 1 (200)</li>
   <li><strong>Page Range:</strong> XX 65-80</li>
   <li><strong>Page Count:</strong> XX 15</li>
   <li><strong>Language:</strong> XX Polish</li>
</ul>
</body>
)

document := ComObjCreate("HTMLfile")
document.write(html)

; To skip a variable, change it to: "" (as shown, where only first 3 are shown
test := ["Issue Year:", "Issue No:", "Page Range:", "", ""]

try While (x := document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[A_Index-1])
    {
    if (x.className = "article-additional-info")
        {
        count++
        yclass%count% := x.innerHTML
        }
    }

loop, %count%
{
which++
html := yclass%A_Index%

document.Close
document := ComObjCreate("HTMLfile")
document.write(html)

try While (x := document.getElementsByTagName("strong")[A_Index-1])
    {
    StringLen, y, % test[A_Index]
    if (test[A_Index] <> "")
        msgbox % which . ": " . test[A_Index] . " " . substr(x.parentnode.innerText, y+2)
    }
}
ExitApp
```

Where the `substr(x.parentnode.innerText, y+2)` is the value you are looking for.

Have Fun!!

Comment: Could you have a look at my question? I'd like to get rid of '"Language:"'.

Comment: See my comment above @menteith for how to remove a variable ("`Language:`") (or any variables) from the results.  You have to leave that  or those value(s) as empty quotes `""`in the `test[array]` and add a line to test for non-empty variable names: `if (test[A_Index] <> "")` to decide if the MsgBox should be shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily manipulate HTML through the [COM](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ComObjCreate.htm) Object [HTMLFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and parse the resulting Text using [StrSplit()](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/StringSplit.htm). Below is an example using the HTML and DOM query you provided:

```
html =
(
<ul class="article-additional-info">
   <li><strong>Issue Year:</strong> 2011</li>
   <li><strong>Issue No:</strong> 1 (200)</li>
   <li><strong>Page Range:</strong> 65-80</li>
   <li><strong>Page Count:</strong> 15</li>
   <li><strong>Language:</strong> Polish</li>
</ul>
)

document := ComObjCreate("HTMLfile")
document.write(html)
x := document.getElementsByClassName("article-additional-info")[0].innerText
MsgBox % StrSplit(StrSplit(x, "`n", "`r").5, " ").2
```

Edit:

```
url := "https://www.ceeol.com/search/article-detail?id=134854"

html := getPage(url) 

document := ComObjCreate("HTMLfile")
document.write(html)
x := document.getElementsByClassName("article-additional-info")[0].innerText
For k, v in StrSplit(x, "`n", "`r") {
    r .= StrSplit(v, ": ").2 "`n"
}

MsgBox % r

getPage(url) {
    whr := ComObjCreate("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    whr.Open("GET", URL, true)
    whr.Send()
    ; Using 'true' above and the call below allows the script to remain responsive.
    whr.WaitForResponse()
    return whr.ResponseText
}
```

Another example using [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```
wb := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
wb.Visible := True
wb.Navigate("https://www.ceeol.com/search/article-detail?id=134854")
While wb.Busy
    sleep 100

loop, 3
    r.= wb.document.querySelectorAll(".article-additional-info li")[a_Index-1].lastChild.nodeValue "`n"
msgbox % r

wb.quit()
exitapp
```

Comment: It will show all the information in `article-additional-info`. What I'd like to get is only a part of it, e.g. `Polish`.

Comment: @ahkcoder for me, I get this error:   


`Error:  0x80020006 - Unknown name.
Specifically: getElementsByClassName


---> 018: x := document.getElementsByClassName("article-additional-info")[0].innerText`


Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure, maybe try reinstalling or even just rebooting. https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/93113-error-0x80020006-unknown-name-when-working-with-ie/

Comment: I'd like to point out some inconsistencies in your statements. First @PGLim Care to explain why the Error you posted is showing that an issue at Line 18 when my example is only 15 lines of code? This implies that you are running code that I did not post. menteith Your first statement implies that the code worked before my edit and that it showed all the text from Class, this was correct at the time. After I edited the code and only added an assignment to x and then StrSplit() he states it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Your first code was _exactly_ the same as mine so it worked.

Comment: When I use `IE.Navigate("https://www.ceeol.com/search/article-detail?id=134854")` (this html code is from there) and `x := IE.document.getElementsByClassName("article-additional-info")[0].innerText` everything works just fine! However, how do I get other pieces than `Polish` (I'm interested in first three)? I've played with the values but with no luck.

Comment: Hrm, seems I wasn't parsing right, needed to split on ": " instead of just " " I added code to retrieve the webpage, without using Internet Explorer, should be a lot faster for you.

Comment: @ahkcoder I put extra line breaks in and an extra MsgBox (showing `document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].innerText` just to make sure I was reading the `html` file in the first place.  But if you look through these forums you will see numerous q's re `getElementsByClassName` because for many people it works only spottily.  Note the absence of a reference to `getElementsByClassName` in Jethrow's seminal "Basic Webpage Controls with JavaScript / COM - Tutorial" at https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/47052-basic-webpage-controls-with-javascript-com-tutorial/

Comment: @ahkcoder Your code including `getElementsByClassName` works for me if I use the retrieved URL (as shown in your edited example); but it does not work for me using an assigned html text (as I show in my examples, and as OP had).  So maybe there is some inconsistency with `getElementsByClassName` depending on the page coding of the text written by `document.write(html)`?  What do you think?

Comment: @PGilm Is your script file encoded with Utf-8 without BOM?

Comment: Since different encodings I prefer to use IE rather than `whr := ComObjCreate("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")`. IE deals correctly with different encodings and `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1` fails at some occaions.

Comment: I meant different encodings of web pages. Your script is very nice and clean.